# I have pushed my changes to github. but i am not able to see the changes on my website?

Tags: html, css, github

I have got domain name from github student pack . i  have uploaded my website and i am able to access it .i made some changes to my codes and pushed it to gihub. but i am not able to see changes on my website.

Comment: You will need to pull the new code from git to your server and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

Github is just a repository - It will not automatically update your website when you push changes. You will need to pull your new updates from github and serve them up from your server.